# Gazebo World Reset

Tags: gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I need to reset the world in Gazebo. I know it can be done manually using the Gazebo GUI and doing Ctrl-R but I need to do it programmatically. I have genetic algorithms running in Visual Studio in Windows and I am communicating with ROS mater using rosserial_windows. Now after every generation I need to reset the world since I am evolving controllers for the robot. How and where should I do this?

Thanks,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/250656/gazebo-world-reset/) by [imranz30](https://answers.ros.org/users/27446/imranz30/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2016-12-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-12-23**:
You might have better luck asking this over at `answers.gazebosim.org`. If you do, please close the question here.

**Comment by [imranz30](https://answers.ros.org/users/27446/imranz30/) on 2017-01-03**:
Solution found and posted on answers.gazebosim.org. So I am closing the question here.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-01-15**:
It would be nice if you could link us to your question on `answers.gazebosim.org`. That way future readers that happen to come across this question can find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/15085/gazebo-world-reset-using-ros/

---

Originally posted by [imranz30](https://answers.ros.org/users/27446/imranz30/) with karma: 26 on 2017-01-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0